# PHP cURL to Facebook insights report

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-marketing-api

I am using the Facebook [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9) with [php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk) to generate my insight report.

When my report is created successfully I can download it from browser in this URL:

> www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=RUN_ID&format=csv&access_token=TOKEN

```
$fileName = "campaign_insights.csv";
$graph_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id='.$report_run.'&format=csv&access_token='.$access_token;

$path = "campaign_insights.csv";

set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

But when I try to download with php to my server with `cURL` or `file_get_contents` I can't. In cURL the response is empty.

What can I do to save the csv in my server?

*Please excuse my English, I speak Spanish.*

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your php code to download the report?

Comment: @ChinLeung i already added the php code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the return transfer option for curl.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

**Note**: The return transfer option must be set to true **before** the file option.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

### Update

After some debugging, if you look at the response of Facebook, you get the error message that the browser of curl is outdated.

So to bypass that:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
));
```

So the whole code would be:

```
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @JoseFlores Take a look at my update. It should work properly now! :)

Comment: No problem @JoseFlores :)